# Reducing Django Database Queries

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-templates, django-views

I have very large dataset and growing, and I need to create many filters but it is going to quickly get out of control and was hoping someone can help me combine some of the queries into a single call.  Below is the start of my view.

**Call #1 - for loop to display table of all results**

`traffic = Traffic.objects.all()`

**Call #2 - Combined aggregate sum query**

```
totals = Traffic.objects.aggregate(Sum('sessions'), Sum('new_users'), Sum('reminder'), Sum('campaigns'), Sum('new_sales'), Sum('sales_renewals'))
    total_sessions = totals.get('sessions__sum')
    total_new_users = totals.get('new_users__sum')
    total_reminder = totals.get('reminder__sum')
    total_campaigns = totals.get('campaigns__sum')
    total_new_sales = totals.get('new_sales__sum')
    total_sales_renewals = totals.get('sales_renewals__sum')
```

**Call #3, #4, #5, #6 and so on... - To filter the database by month and day of week**

```
total_sessions_2014_m = Traffic.objects.filter(created__year='2014', created__week_day=2).aggregate(Sum('sessions'))

total_sessions_2014_m = Traffic.objects.filter(created__year='2014', created__week_day=3).aggregate(Sum('sessions'))

total_sessions_2014_m = Traffic.objects.filter(created__year='2014', created__week_day=4).aggregate(Sum('sessions'))

total_sessions_2014_m = Traffic.objects.filter(created__year='2014', created__week_day=5).aggregate(Sum('sessions'))

total_sessions_2014_m = Traffic.objects.filter(created__year='2014', created__week_day=6).aggregate(Sum('sessions'))
```

The problem is , I need to create several dozen more filters because I have 3 years of data with multiple data points per column that we need totals the sum for.

**Questions:**

1. Can I combine call #1 into call #2
2. Can I use Call #2 to query the sums for call#3 so I don't have to call all objects from the database to filter it and then do this a couple more dozen times?

As you can see, this is going to get out of control very quickly.  Any help would be hugely appreciated.  Thank you.

**Updated to add
Traffic Model**

```
class Timestamp(models.Model):
    created = models.DateField()

    class Meta:
        abstract = True


class Traffic(Timestamp):
    sessions = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    new_users = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    reminder = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    campaigns = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    new_sales = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    sales_renewals = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)

    # Meta and String
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Traffic'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Traffic Data'

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s" % self.created
```

Comment: Are all these data shown on the template  at a time ?

Comment: Can you update your question with adding `Traffic` model ?

Comment: @ParagTyagi-morpheus- Yes, these will be in same view.  Its a tool for my inhouse marketing department and will be served from our internal server.  This is just the tip of the iceberg,  I have mountains of data to move from Excel, so having different views is not an option. Just updated with my `traffic` model.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

There are dozens of ways to optimize your database queries with the Django ORM. As usual, the [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/optimization/) is great and has a good list of them. Here's some quick tips for query optimization:

**1)** [`iterator()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#iterator)

If you are accessing the `queryset` only once. So for example you can use this as,

```
traffic = Traffic.objects.all()

for t in traffic.iterator():
    ...
    ...
```

---

**2)** [`db_index=True`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/fields/#db-index)

While defining fields of your `models`. As the [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/optimization/#use-standard-db-optimization-techniques) says,

> This is a number one priority, after you have determined from
> profiling what indexes should be added. Use Field.db_index or
> Meta.index_together to add these from Django. Consider adding indexes
> to fields that you frequently query using filter(), exclude(),
> order_by(), etc. as indexes may help to speed up lookups.

Hence you can modify your model as,

```
class Traffic(Timestamp):
    sessions = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True, db_index=True)
    new_users = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True, db_index=True)
    reminder = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True, db_index=True)
    campaigns = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True, db_index=True)
    new_sales = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True, db_index=True)
```

---

**3)** [`prefetch_related()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related) or [`select_related()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#select-related)

If you have relations within your `models`, using `prefetch_related` or `select_related` would be a choice. As per the [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/),

`select_related` works by creating a `SQL join` and including the fields of the related object in the SELECT statement. For this reason, `select_related` gets the related objects in the same database query. However, to avoid the much larger result set that would result from joining across a 'many' relationship, `select_related` is limited to single-valued relationships - foreign key and one-to-one.

`prefetch_related`, on the other hand, does a separate lookup for each
relationship, and does the 'joining' in Python. This allows it to prefetch
many-to-many and many-to-one objects, which cannot be done using
`select_related`, in addition to the foreign key and one-to-one relationships that are supported by `select_related`.

`select_related` does a `join`, `prefetch_related` does two separate queries. Using these you can make your queries upto 30% faster.

---

**4)** [Django Pagination](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/pagination/)

If your `template` design allows you to display results in multiple pages your can use `Pagination`.

---

**5)** [Querysets are Lazy](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/queries/#querysets-are-lazy)

You also need to understand that the Django Querysets are lazy which means that it won't query the database untill its being used/evaluated. A queryset in Django represents a number of rows in the database, optionally filtered by a query. For example,

```
traffic = Traffic.objects.all()
```

The above code doesn’t run any database queries. You can can take the `traffic` queryset and apply additional filters, or pass it to a function, and nothing will be sent to the database. This is good, because querying the database is one of the things that significantly slows down web applications. To fetch the data from the database, you need to iterate over the queryset:

```
for t in traffic.iterator():
    print(t.sessions)
```

---

**6)** [django-debug-toolbar](https://github.com/robhudson/django-debug-toolbar)

Django Debug Toolbar is a configurable set of panels that display various debug information about the current request/response and when clicked, display more details about the panel's content. This includes:

- Request timer
- SQL queries including time to execute and links to EXPLAIN each query

---

**Modifying your code**: (remember *Querysets are Lazy*)

```
traffic = Traffic.objects.all()
totals = traffic.aggregate(Sum('sessions'), Sum('new_users'), Sum('reminder'), Sum('campaigns'), Sum('new_sales'), Sum('sales_renewals'))
total_sessions = totals.get('sessions__sum')
total_new_users = totals.get('new_users__sum')
total_reminder = totals.get('reminder__sum')
total_campaigns = totals.get('campaigns__sum')
total_new_sales = totals.get('new_sales__sum')
total_sales_renewals = totals.get('sales_renewals__sum')

t_2014 = traffic.filter(created__year='2014')
t_sessions_2014_wd2 = t_2014.filter(created__week_day=2).aggregate(Sum('sessions'))
...
...
```

For **Call #1** in template (for loop to display table of all results):

```
{% for t in traffic.iterator %}
    {{ t.sessions }}
    ...
    ...
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: wow, thank you for a lot of great info!  I just arrived at the office and will need some to consume it all but will report back on how things progress and the final solution that worked.

Comment: I was already using the django-debug-toolbar, but applying iterator(), I was able to reduce my queries a bit.  I'll certainly need to keep tweaking to keep my queries to a minimum, but this set me in the right direction; thank you for the detailed response...it's lead me to research other areas I wasn't aware of.

Answer (score 3):

As for Question 1, it shouldn't be a problem to reuse the queryset from the first call.

```
traffic = Traffic.objects.all()
totals = traffic.aggregate(Sum('sessions'), Sum('new_users'), Sum('reminder'), Sum('campaigns'), Sum('new_sales'), Sum('sales_renewals'))
```

This should spare you an additional call to the database.

Regarding Question 2, you can again reuse the queryset from the first call, and filter the year, which gives you a new queryset, e.g.

```
traffic_2014 = traffic.filter(created__year='2014')
```

You can then continue filtering the days and aggregating with this new queryset, like you did before, or create new querysets for each day, assuming you aggregate multiple attributes every day, thus saving you another dozen database calls.

I hope this helps you.

Answer (score 2):

Not addressing the questions directly, but I think you should consider a different approach.

Based on my understanding:

- The view may be requested often.
- The data should change rarely.
- There is a need for complicated data manipulation (summing fields by year, month, day etc.)

There is no need to perform the same queries each time someone requests the view.

Load all the data in one step and perform manipulations inside the view. You can use a library like [Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) and create complicated data sets. The view will be now CPU bound so use a caching system like [Redis](http://redis.io/) to avoid recalculating. Invalidate when the data has changed.

Another approach: perform the calculations periodically by using a task queue like [Celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/) and populate Redis.